# Protractor persistent variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm trying to set up something similar to the Environment / Global variables in Postman. Postman stores these variables in JSON and when you modify them within a test, they will be the changed to the new values permanently. For example:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("variable1", parseInt(postman.getEnvironmentVariable) +1);
```

This function would increment the Environment Variable by 1 at the start of a request. In my real Postman tests I use a custom function to calculate a valid EAN13 barcode based on the previously used barcode as they must be unique.

Is there anything like this that can be achieved in Protractor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an elegant solution to this. I import my `params` in a JSON object like below:

```
global.DATA_PATH = './data/environment.json';
global.fs = require(fs);
exports.config = {
    ...
    params: {
        data = require(global.DATA_PATH)
    }
    ...
};
```

Then in my JSON object I'll define the data like so:

```
{
    "variable1": "blah"
}
```

Now I can access my data through normal object dot notation in my code:

```
this.modifyVariable1 = function(value) {
    params.data.variable1 = value;
}
```

Since this just modifies the variable `params.data.variable1` in the parameters, I sync it with the file by using the nodejs module `fs` in `afterAll`:

```
afterAll(function() {
    global.fs.writeFile(global.DATA_PATH, (JSON.stringify(params.data), null, 4), 'utf8);
});
```

This only needs to be run when the spec is done because changes to the params object persist through each `it` statement.

Hope this helps others who wanted to try something similar!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `'params'` object for storing data. You can set it up in the config file. [config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)

```
params: {
      login: {
        user: 'Jane',
        password: '1234'
      }
    }
```

Accessed from the browser object like `browser.params.login`. You can change the value of the object which can be retrieved in another test.

Comment: But won't the params reset back to what they originally were once all tests are run? That won't work because suddenly the EAN13 barcode isn't unique anymore and I have to deduce which barcode to use every time I run my tests.

Comment: You are correct it will not persist after test completes. process.env.somevariable also will not make this permanent. How about storing this value in a file?

Comment: I did think of this but I wasn't able to find any way to do this in any neat way. Should I define an uninstantiated global variable and then define a helper function and call it in Jasmine's beforeEach or afterEach functions?